# Where can I find Hostelworld's rankings for cities?

Tags: hostelworld

Every time you leave a review on Hostelworld, the website asks you to add a review for the city where you were staying:

[image]

But where can one then see these reviews on the Hostelworld website? I'd love to find out the rankings for some cities I am planning to visit, as well as to read the recommendations.

Comment: It's possible they're just saving them for some future feature there or on hostels.com, where the city guides are woefully out-of-date, and were not very good even when originally published.

Comment: @choster if so, they've been doing it for many years now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At of this moment — nowhere. They are probably planning to create some sort of a crowdfunded travel guide, but currently it's not available anywhere.